# Golang + GORM Fetch foreign key with raw query

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have question regarding fetching foreign key in GORM.
I am using `golang` and `POSTGRES` for my database.
AFAIK, `Preload(clause.Associations)` will fetch the foreign key from our database.

If we are using Gorm `.Find(&model)`, its automatically fetching my foreign key detail
But if I am using Raw Query `.Raw()`, its not fetching the foreign key

here is the example
my model

```
type BankAccount struct {
    gorm.Model `json:"-"`

    ID    uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4();primary_key" json:"id"`
    OrgId uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;not null" json:"orgId"`

    AccountName   string    `gorm:"not null" json:"accountName"`
    AccountNumber string    `gorm:"not null" json:"accountNumber"`
    AccountType   string    `gorm:"not null" json:"accountType"`
    BankId        uuid.UUID `gorm:"not null" json:"bankId"`
    Bank          *Bank     `gorm:"foreignKey:BankAccountId" json:"bank"`
}
```

if I use `db.Preload(clause.Associations).Find(&BankAccount)`, it automatically fetching `bank` field.

```
{
    "id": "999e5e1f-dfd2-498f-a856-6a021052",
    "orgId": "bbd38cbe-3eef-4587-a178-eb3148",
    "accountName": "Account 1 Neo Bank",
    "accountNumber": "8237372323",
    "accountType": "debit",
    "bankId": "89c-5ff8-4b13-b8c3-dd3b3be690b5",
    "bank": {
        "id": "89c-5ff8-4b13-b8c3-dd3b3be690b5",
        "orgId": "bbd38cbe-3eef-4587-a178-eb316b729148",
        "name": "Neo Bank",
        "address": "Addr 2",
        "contactInfo": "081333333",
        "remarks": "neo bank"
    }
}
```

but if I am using raw query like this `db.Preload(clause.Associations).Raw("select * from bank_account").scan(&bankAccounts)`, it wont fetch the `bank` field

```
[
{
    "id": "999e5e1f-dfd2-498f-a856-6a021052",
    "orgId": "bbd38cbe-3eef-4587-a178-eb3148",
    "accountName": "Account 1 Neo Bank",
    "accountNumber": "8237372323",
    "accountType": "debit",
    "bankId": "89c-5ff8-4b13-b8c3-dd3b3be690b5",
    "bank": null
}
]
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using raw query that means gorm will execute this plain query without modifying any thing into it. So gorm will not join `bank_account` table with `bank` table. You have to explicitly do that.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question.

Actually I am not doing it wrong.
It just `.Preload()` cant run if we use `Raw()`.

and here is what I discover:

Recently, I saw the log from GORM using `.Debug()` func.
`.Preload()` actually running another query and put the result on the `struct` result.

Now, I changing my method to use `.Raw()` function and make another `struct` to put the result. and it works fine.
whenever I have a complex query, I will use this method.

Hope it helps
Thanks